# How does the percentile function work in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Imagine the following column calledd `id`:

68
69
43
54
56
61
69
70
71
72
77
78
79
85
87
88
89
93
95
96
98
99
99
62
66

If I do the following: `percentile(id, 0.9)`, the output is 97.2. What is going on?

Comment: In addition to Andrea Romagnoli's answer I would like to mention that one of the common uses of percentile is finding the median value like so: percentile(id, 0.5)

Comment: Also interesting to know how hive decentralizes this operation efficiently

Answer (score 13):

If you put 0.9, you expect that the 90% of the data you give to the function will be under the returned value. 90% of 25 is approximately 22.5, and 97.2 can be a correct answer, because the four highest values are 99 99 98 96 in your set, and 97.2 is between the 22nd (96) and the 23rd (98) ordered numbers.